# How to select the parent node if the child node equals specific value in xslt using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

My XML looks like

```
<Subjects>
    <subject>
        <id>Maths</id>
        <sid>12</sid>
    </subject>
    <subject>
        <id>science</id>
        <sid>13</sid>
    </subject>
    <subject>
        <id>social</id>
        <sid>14</sid>
    </subject>
</Subjects>

 <xsl:variable name="Msubject" select="../../id[text()='Maths']"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="$Msubject/sid/text()" />

 <xsl:template match="//subject[id='Maths']/sid">
      <xsl:copy>
        22
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I need the to get the subject where id = Maths and change its sid to 22(or requried value). Similary i need to get the subject where id is science and change its sid to 23 etc tried above whhich is not working**

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the additional inputs provided in the question, the solution has been modified and it can now be used for replacing the value in `<sid>` with the value available in a different file.

**File1.xml**

```
<Subjects>
    <subject>
        <id>Maths</id>
        <sid>12</sid>
    </subject>
    <subject>
        <id>science</id>
        <sid>13</sid>
    </subject>
    <subject>
        <id>social</id>
        <sid>14</sid>
    </subject>
</Subjects>
```

**File2.xml**

```
<inputfile>
    <mathsid>22</mathsid>
    <scienceid>23</scienceid>
    <socialid>24</socialid>
</inputfile>
```

The XSLT uses logic to read the value of `<id>` from `File1.xml` and create a node out of it viz. `<Mathsid>`,`<scienceid>` and `<socialid>`. Using this fabricated node it looks up in `File2.xml` for nodes that contain similar name. The matching is done from the 2nd character so that uppercase M in `<Mathsid>` does not create issues with `<mathsid>`. It can also be achieved by converting the camel case node name to lower case but XSLT 1.0 requires additional work to handle it.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:param name="file" select="document('File2.xml')/inputfile" />

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- for all 'subject' nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="subject">
        <!-- create variable to fabricate a node name i.e. Mathsid, scienceid, 
             socialid using the value in <id> and string 'id' -->         
        <xsl:variable name="subjNameNode" select="concat(id, 'id')" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- copy the value of node id as is -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="id" />
            <!-- replace existing value of 'sid' by value from the different file by checking
                 whether the node name contains the explicitly created above. The check is done 
                 from the 2nd character so that <mathsid> contains text 'athsid' -->
            <sid>
                <xsl:value-of select="$file/*[contains(local-name(), substring($subjNameNode,2))]" />
            </sid>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSLT when used with `File1.xml` transforms it and produces the desired output.

**Output**

```
<Subjects>
    <subject>
        <id>Maths</id>
        <sid>22</sid>
    </subject>
    <subject>
        <id>science</id>
        <sid>23</sid>
    </subject>
    <subject>
        <id>social</id>
        <sid>24</sid>
    </subject>
</Subjects>
```

Comment: @Anikt it works but i need something like this, i need to fetch the sid of maths and change it to my required value in that case   <xsl:template match="//subject[id='Maths']/sid">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$inputFile/build/host/text()" />
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: matching the subject maths and changing the sid of the maths subject is what i need to be precise

Comment: waiting for your answer@Ankit

Comment: There is no code shared corresponding to `<xsl:value-of select="$inputFile/build/host/text()" />` in the question. The solution is according to the question that was asked. If you need something different, you need to edit the question and provide the additional details or open a new question.

Comment: edited the question as suggested, Thanks for your help

Comment: where do you get the values `22` or `23` from? Are they hard coded or are they mapped in some other file. If there is some mapping, please share the other XML too.

Comment: I have it from other xml, it would look like below
<inputfile>
<mathsid>22</mathsid>
<scienceid>23</scienceid>
<socialid>24</socialid>
</inputfile>

Comment: The solution has been updated to handle the newer requirements and an explanation provided for the logic implemented in the solution.

Comment: If the answer has worked for you, could you please accept the answer. [How to accept the answer and it's benefits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)